# What should I do about code style if a GitHub project is missing CONTRIBUTING.md?

Tags: contributor, collaboration, github

I want to contribute to a C# project on GitHub, but the repository is missing a `CONTRIBUTING.md` file. I've already noticed a few code style inconsistencies, but I don't want to assume the project is using the MSDN code conventions. What is the best way to bring up this issue with the maintainer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general advise - you should try to follow suite. If you're editing a file, follow the conventions it sets. If you're adding a new file, follow the conventions of other files in the same directory.

And when in doubt - just ask. A live project should have a method to contact the maintainer(s) published on its page. Reach out via email/irc/whatever preferred method of communication the project publishes and ask about the style. Chances are the first contribution he'd ask you to make would be to create a `CONTRIBUTING.md` page yourself.

Comment: I would add: If style in a project varies, the existing contributors may not be willing to consider a "house style". If they do consider one, they may not all comply in their own work. If they do comply, they may not wish to enforce the style on incoming pull requests. Asking about the project's attitude to code conventions allows you to gauge where in this spectrum the current project team is.